# How to scrape table data with th and td with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Am new to programming and have been trying to practice web scrapping. Found a example where one of the columns I wish to have in my out put is part of the table header. I am able to extract all the table data I wish, but have been unable to get the Year dates to show.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # this module helps in web scrapping.
import requests  # this module helps us to download a web page
import pandas as pd
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population"
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all('table')
len(tables)
for index,table in enumerate(tables):
    if ("Global annual population growth" in str(table)):
        table_index = index
print(table_index)

print(tables[table_index].prettify())

population_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Year","Population","Growth"])

for row in tables[table_index].tbody.find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all('td')
    if (col !=[]):
        Population = col[0].text.strip()
        Growth = col[1].text.strip()
        population_data = population_data.append({"Population":Population,"Growth":Growth}, ignore_index= True)
        
population_data
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's because you are scraping <td> in this line:

**col = row.find_all('td')**

But if you will take a look at <tr> in developer tools(F12), you can see that table also contains <th> tag which keep the year and which you are not scraping. So everything that you have to do is add this line after **If** condition:

**year = row.find('th').text**, and after that you can append it in population data

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas` directly here to get your goal with [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) to scrape the table and [`pandas.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to transform it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population')[0].T.reset_index()
df.columns = df.loc[0]
df = df[1:]
df
```

or same result with `BeautifulSoup` and `stripped_strings`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population').text)

pd.DataFrame(
    {list(e.stripped_strings)[0]: list(e.stripped_strings)[1:] for e in soup.table.select('tr')}
)
```

##### Output

| Population | Year | Years elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1804 | 200,000+ |
| 2 | 1930 | 126 |
| 3 | 1960 | 30 |
| 4 | 1974 | 14 |
| 5 | 1987 | 13 |
| 6 | 1999 | 12 |
| 7 | 2011 | 12 |
| 8 | 2022 | 11 |
| 9 | 2037 | 15 |
| 10 | 2057 | 20 |